# Sorting a list by the modulus of 3

Tags: java, sorting, set

The input is an unsorted array of integers. The output should be an array of integers sorted based on the modulus of 3 (or any other number).

It begins with all integers conforming to Integer % 3 == 0 then 1 and then 2.

```
public class sortByMod {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    int a[] = {1,90,2100, 12, 24, 80, 90, 5};
    LinkedList<List<Integer>> a1=sortMod(a);
    for(int i=0; i <a1.size();i++)
            System.out.print(a1.get(i)+" ");
}

public static LinkedList sortMod(int a[]){
    HashMap<Integer, TreeSet<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, TreeSet<Integer>>();
    for(Integer i =0; i<a.length;i++){
        Integer modKey = a[i]%3;
        if(!map.containsKey(modKey)){
            map.put(modKey, new TreeSet<Integer>());
        }
        TreeSet<Integer> temp = map.get(modKey);
        temp.add(a[i]);
        map.put(modKey,temp);
    }
    LinkedList<List<Integer>> result= new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
    TreeSet<Integer> temp;
    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++) {

        if(map.containsKey(i)){
           temp = map.get(i);
        }
        else return null;

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(temp);
        result.add(list);

    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code definitely doesn't work with any number except 3, and it's quite likely you'll make an error if you'll be changing the code to another number. So I'd use

```
public LinkedList sortMod(int a[], int number)
```

instead. Also, the code returns `null` when there's no numbers of any modulus. I.e. `sortMod(new int[]{1})` returns `null` as well as `sortMod(new int[]{1, 4, 7, 10, 13})`.

You can also try to use Streams, feature of Java 8. For example, the single line

```
return map.values().stream().map(ArrayList::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

does a lot of job, effectively replacing 10 lines of your code. You can try to make the task in two lines using Java 8 features. Also it works fine with `sortMod(new int[]{1, 4, 7, 10, 13})`.

Answer (score 2):

#### [Do not use raw-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Really, don't. The method `sortMod` is currently returning a raw `LinkedList`:

```
public static LinkedList sortMod(int a[])
```

Consider changing that so that it returns, in your case, a `LinkedList<List<Integer>>`.

#### Use the enhanced for loop

The code is currently populating a temporary `Map<Integer, TreeSet<Integer>` with

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    // do something with a[i]
}
```

When you don't need the index, using an enhanced for loop makes the code more compact and easier to read. Consider having instead

```
for (Integer element : a) {
    // do something with element
}
```

#### Write code [against interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

The following construct all write code against a specific concrete implementation:

```
HashMap<Integer, TreeSet<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, TreeSet<Integer>>();
// ...
LinkedList<List<Integer>> result = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
// ...
public static LinkedList<List<Integer>> sortMod(int a[])
```

It is preferable to use top-level interfaces instead, to hide the concrete implementations. Here, it would be:

```
Map<Integer, TreeSet<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, TreeSet<Integer>>();
// ...
List<List<Integer>> result = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
// ...
public static List<List<Integer>> sortMod(int a[])
```

Also, you don't even need a `LinkedList`. Except for very specific operations, like adding or removing an element through an iterator, a linked list [will be a lot slower than a `ArrayList`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist). As such, consider just using a simple `ArrayList`.

An additional point: since Java 7, you can use the [diamond operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7) and write less concise code with generic classes instantiation. You can just have:

```
Map<Integer, TreeSet<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
// ...
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
```

#### Beware of returning `null`

When the input array doesn't have an element that is divisible by 3, your code will return `null` explicitely. This is handled as

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    if (map.containsKey(i)) {
        temp = map.get(i);
    } else
        return null;
    // ...
}
```

Apart from the missing curly braces, that are always preferable to add, returning `null` in this case is both surprising and the source of bugs:

- Surprising, because a caller of the method will not expect

  ```
  int array[] = { 1, 3 };
  System.out.println(sortMod(array));
  ```

  to print `null`, especially that

  ```
  int array[] = { 1, 3, 2 };
  System.out.println(sortMod(array));
  ```

  would print `[[3], [1], [2]]`.

  A given method should always try to respect the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). When called with an array of `{ 1, 3 }`, the caller would expect as result `[[3], [1], []]`, that is a list which contains 3 as the only number divisible by 3, then 1 as the only number whose remainder by 3 is 1, and then an empty list since no elements have a remainder of 2 when divided by 3.
- Source of bugs, because the caller will have to do a `null`-check before doing any operations, which will often be forgotten, leading to `NullPointerException`s. [It is preferable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969993/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-collection) to return empty collections rather than `null`.

#### Leverage the Stream API

Starting from Java 8, the code can be greatly simplified using the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) ([tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/)):

```
public static List<List<Integer>> sortMod(int a[]) {
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map =
        Arrays.stream(a)
              .boxed()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i % 3, Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new)));
    return map.values().stream().map(ArrayList<Integer>::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This does the same task, but in a handful of lines of code.

- The first part creates the intermediate map storing the result of the modulo by 3 with their respective numbers. The work is all done by the [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector, which groups elements classified to a same key and hands those element to a downstream collector. Here, the classifier returns the result of the modulo by 3, and the downstream collector, collecting elements grouped to the same key, collects them into a `TreeSet` with [`toCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection-java.util.function.Supplier-).
- The second part post-processes that map by mapping each value into an `ArrayList` and collecting all those lists into a new list.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to achive this that I can think of uses the `Collections.sort()` method and a `Comparator`.

```java
int a[] = {23,35,7,125,3,12,6,356};
List<Integer> sorted = new LinkedList<>();
for(int i: a){
  sorted.add(i);
}
Collections.sort(sorted, (i1, i2) -> i1%3 > i2%3?1:-1);
System.out.println(sorted);
```

The `Comparator` (instanciated by a lmbda expression) compares the mod 3 values of 2 integers and either return that the first is bigget than (return 1) or smaller than (return -1) the second mod 3 value. 
The sort method will sort the list by that criteria.

You'd have to make a more detailed comparator if you wanted the smallest of the integers to be first if multiple of them have the same mod 3.

My examples output was

```
[6, 12, 3, 7, 356, 125, 35, 23]
```